# TypeScript: Why having a `keyof` here can solve this issue

Tags: typescript

I was trying to write a function to return an array of values in an object

```js
let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}

const r = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  let val = obj[key]
  return val
})
```

Here the TS compiler showed an error saying that

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: number; b: number; c:
> number; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was
> found on type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'.ts(7053)

I cannot decipher what it means but I thought it has something to do with `key` being a string. so I tried this instead

```
let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}

const r = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  let val = obj[key as keyof typeof obj] // the error now is gone
  return val
})

console.log('r', r)
```

Now there is no error. I am not exactly sure why. all I know is that `keyof` would yields the type of permitted property names on the `obj` but I don't know what purpose `typeof` serves here

Answer (score 1):

Typescript infers the typing of your `obj` object to be:

```js
type Obj = {
  a: number
  b: number
  c: number
}
```

This can also be expressed as:

```js
type Obj = {[key in 'a' | 'b' | 'c']: number};
```

`'a' | 'b' | 'c'` is a subtype of `string`. When you use `Object.keys(obj)` however, typescript infers the return type here to be `string[]` as opposed to `('a' | 'b' | 'c')[]`. This is why it complains about `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'` - because you cannot use any `string` to look up values in `obj`, rather you need to use specific keys.

The `keyof` operator takes a type as an input, and returns the keys provided. The reason you need `typeof` is to infer the type of an object (otherwise you'd be doing `keyof obj`, which typescript does not understand as `obj` is not a type)

`keyof typeof obj` is inferred as `"a" | "b" | "c"`

Keyof - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types

Typeof - https://mariusschulz.com/blog/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript#typescripts-type-queries